# How do you add a fixed angle to the RigidBody 2D in Unity 5.2.0

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've looked through other threads and can't seem to find the constraints section in my RigidBody.

I'm kind of new to Unity and I don't have much experience...

Answer (score 1):

In your `Rigidbody 2D` component click on `Constraints` and then select `Freeze Rotation`

See last line of below image

[image]

Comment: How do you get the constraints menu up?

Comment: click on the > Contraints

Comment: 5.2.0 nvm. Are you sure you added a rigidbody 2D and not a rigidbody 3D?

Comment: Even 3D should have it. Click on the triangle before the `Constraints`, not on the word itself

Comment: The constraints menu is simply not on my rigid body on my unity file... Underneath collision detection there is nothing but another controller